# How to get a list of variables separated by comma, as input for a function, from a sting in R

Tags: r

I am working with the `mc2d packages` and I would like to combine several `u-nodes`. As follows:

```
a=mcstoc(func=rpert, type = "U", min = 1, mode=10, max=20, nsu = I)
b=mcstoc(func=rpert, type = "U", min = 1, mode=100, max=200, nsu = I)
mc(a,b)   node    mode nsv    nsu nva variate  min  mean median   max Nas type outm 1    a numeric   1 100000   1       1 1.05  10.2  
10.1  19.8   0    U each 2    b numeric   1 100000   1       1 3.21 100.3  100.2 197.9   0    U each
```

However the names of the nodes tha I want to combine are stored in a string variable like this:

```
c=c("a","b")
```

Now I would like to make the `“mc”` command work with this string variable. However my attempts fail:

```
mc(c)
Error in mc(c) : arguments should be mc or mcnode objects
mc(paste(c, collapse=", "))
Error in mc(paste(c, collapse = ", ")) : 
  arguments should be mc or mcnode objects
mc(mget(c))
Error in mc(mget(c)) : arguments should be mc or mcnode object
```

How can I get the `“mc”` command to work with my string variable?

Comment: `pair <- c("a", "b") ; do.call(mc, lapply(pair, get))`

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I use: 
do.call(mc, mget(pair))